# how can i solve bandwidth and Shannon capacity in matlab

Tags: matlab

C= B log2 (1+SNR) how can plot this in matlab

```
figure('Color', 'white')
SNR = 1000 ;
B =  4.* 10^6 ;
C = (4 .*10^6) .* log2(1+1000);  
plot(C)
xlabel('SNR'); 
ylabel('B (MHz)'); 
title('Throuput')
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more, what do you want to achieve? Luis's sample code is plotting the Channel capacity Vs SNR

Answer (score 1):

To plot C as a function of SNR:

```
SNR = logspace(-1,2,1000); %// choose as desired
B = 4e6;
C = B*log2(1+SNR);

plot(10*log10(SNR),C) %// SNR in dB
xlabel('SNR (dB)')
ylabel('Capacity (bit/s)')
```

Or

```
plot(SNR,C) %// SNR in natural units
xlabel('SNR')
ylabel('Capacity (bit/s)')
```